# Drupal ahah returns (An HTTP error 404 occurred) but path is working on browser and with jquery ajax

Tags: ajax, drupal, ahah

i have created a form to arrange some names in orders by drag n drop. IN this form user can add dynamic form element by add more button as we do in cck.
my code is working find on localhost and i can add form element dynamic and it is getting submited fine. but on live server when i press add more button it return  "An HTTP error 404 occurred". i executed this path on browser address bar directly then it works and give me json result. when i tried to execute it with jquery ajax it returns (200 OK 1.4s). i am very confuse what is happening with ahah. 
if anyone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

mmmm not understanding your situation perfectly but  try to use

print drupal_to_js($result)  ; 
exit() ;

when you printing your json  data